# Expression of the Equations of 3D Egg Shape in terms of degrees

Tags: 3d

I'd basically like to have 3D version of [this article section](http://www16.ocn.ne.jp/~akiko-y/Egg_by_Itou/index_egg_by_Itou_E.html) or [this section](http://www16.ocn.ne.jp/~akiko-y/Egg/index_egg_E.html#3). So for my case, there are two angles for latitude and longitude to construct 3D egg. Any hint to extend the formula to 3D would be appreciated.

Comment: "Fig. 2a Comparison between the egg shaped curve
of $b=0.7a$ and the shape of an actual egg." Awesome.

Comment: The links in this question have gone stale. Is there a way to update the question with the applicable content from the cited articles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you want the parametric form of the [surface of revolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html) of a chosen curve.

If your curve given by some functions $x = f(\theta)$ and $y = g(\theta)$, the surface of revolution about the $x$-axis is parametrized by
$$\begin{align}
x &= f(\theta), \\
y &= g(\theta)\cos(\phi), \\
z &= g(\theta)\sin(\phi),
\end{align}$$
where $\theta$ has the same range in as your input curve and $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $360$ degrees.

Answer (score 4):

The link to the article that was originally cited for this question has gone stale, so I thought I would post the egg shape that I came up with back in 2004:
$$
\begin{align}
x(\phi)&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\cos(\phi)&\text{if }-\pi\le\phi\lt0\\
-1+2\cos(\phi)&\text{if }0\le\phi\lt\frac\pi4\\
\left(2-\sqrt2\right)\cos(\phi)\phantom{1+\,}&\text{if }\frac\pi4\le\phi\lt\frac{3\pi}4\\
1+2\cos(\phi)&\text{if }\frac{3\pi}4\le\phi\lt\pi
\end{array}\right.\\
y(\phi)&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\sin(\phi)&\text{if }-\pi\le\phi\lt0\\
2\sin(\phi)&\text{if }0\le\phi\lt\frac\pi4\\
1+\left(2-\sqrt2\right)\sin(\phi)&\text{if }\frac\pi4\lt\phi\lt\frac{3\pi}4\\
2\sin(\phi)&\text{if }\frac{3\pi}4\le\phi\lt\pi\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
[image]

This was originally visualized as arcs of four circles:

[image]

but it can also be seen as the envelope of a family of circles:

[image]

In $3$ dimensions, we can look at the surface of revolution:

[image]

The $3$ dimensional egg is also an envelope of a family of spheres:

[image]

The parametric equation for the $3$ dimensional egg is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align}
x(\phi,\theta)&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)&\text{if }-\frac\pi2\le\phi\lt0\\
(-1+2\cos(\phi))\cos(\theta)&\text{if }0\le\phi\lt\frac\pi4\\
\left(2-\sqrt2\right)\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)&\text{if }\frac\pi4\le\phi\le\frac\pi2
\end{array}\right.\\
y(\phi,\theta)&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)&\text{if }-\frac\pi2\le\phi\lt0\\
(-1+2\cos(\phi))\sin(\theta)&\text{if }0\le\phi\lt\frac\pi4\\
\left(2-\sqrt2\right)\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)\,&\text{if }\frac\pi4\le\phi\le\frac\pi2
\end{array}\right.\\
z(\phi,\theta)&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\sin(\phi)&\text{if }-\frac\pi2\le\phi\lt0\\
2\sin(\phi)&\text{if }0\le\phi\lt\frac\pi4\\
1+\left(2-\sqrt2\right)\sin(\phi)\phantom{(|\,)}&\text{if }\frac\pi4\le\phi\le\frac\pi2
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}}
$$