# Equation of a 3D egg

Tags: calculus

Does anyone know the equation of a 3-Dimensional egg. Like a real egg( the uneven type where it is more wide on one side), not an ellipsoid in 3D cartesian form.I can't seem to find it anywhere, I mean there is one even for the heart in 3D, so there should be one for an egg right?

Comment: There most certainly exists such an equation, you are right. However, the heart equation is easy to remember and simple to write down, which is why it is often encountered. There is no reason for the egg equation to also match these properties...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267091/expression-of-the-equations-of-3d-egg-shape-in-terms-of-degrees this might help you.

Comment: @MichaelCera Sadly, that question is crippled by link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} x(u,v) = (1 + 0.2 v) \cos u \sin v  \\ y(u,v) = (1+0.2v) \sin u \sin v \\ z(u,v) = 1.65 \cos v  \end{cases}$$

[Here's the source](http://danielwalsh.tumblr.com/post/2742366331/mathematically-defined-easter-eggs#disqus_thread).

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$